# Shared mailbox won't open emails past 1 year in Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, outlook, vdi, azure-virtual-desktop

I have an AVD environment created with a Windows 11 multisession + O365 apps image. A set of users are added to a shared mailbox, Outlook won't show emails past 1 year. Usually in a regular computer that has the same policies, once it passes one year Outlook goes and displays emails directly from the exchange server (365), this is not happening in AVD.

I've tried to recreate profiles with no success. I am expecting to have Outlook query the exchange server (365) and retrieve the emails from the shared mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following steps to set your mailbox to online mode and then check whether you can search for messages older than one year:

1.Open file- info

2.Click Account Settings- Account Settings

3.Select the primary mailbox that has Full Access permissions to the shared mailbox and double-click it.

4.Cancel select ”Use Cached Exchange Mode to download email to an Outlook data file”.

5.Click Next and save this setting.

6.Restart the Outlook client.

Comment: Testing, I will report back as soon as we test this.

Comment: There is a checkbox, Exchange Account Settings > More Settings > Advanced  > "Download shared folders". Unchecking this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a scenario where Outlook isn't displaying emails from a shared mailbox beyond a year, here are some troubleshooting steps you can follow to resolve the issue:

**1. Ensure Email Retention Settings:**

First, check the email retention settings in Office 365. It's possible that the emails older than one year have been archived or moved to a different folder. Confirm the retention policies for the shared mailbox.

**2. Check Cached Mode:**

Verify that Outlook is running in Cached Exchange Mode. Cached mode stores a copy of the mailbox on the local computer, and this copy may not include older emails if the synchronization settings are not configured properly. To change this setting:
Open Outlook.
Click on "File" > "Account Settings" > "Account Settings."
Select the Exchange account and click "Change."
Under "Offline Settings," ensure that "Mail to keep offline" is set to "All."

**3. Manually Download Emails:**

You can manually initiate a full download of emails in Outlook. To do this:
In Outlook, select the shared mailbox.
Go to the "Folder" tab.
Click on "Download Shared Folders."
Check the option for "Download headers and then full items."
Click "OK" to start the download.

**4. Recreate Outlook Profile:**

If the issue persists, try recreating the Outlook profile for the affected user:
Close Outlook.
Go to "Control Panel" > "Mail" (or "Outlook" > "Account Settings" > "Manage Profiles" in newer versions).
Select the existing profile and click "Remove."
Create a new profile, configure the Exchange account, and open Outlook again.

**5. Check AutoArchive Settings:**

Ensure that AutoArchive settings in Outlook are not set to automatically move emails older than a year to an archive folder. To check this:
Go to "File" > "Options" > "Advanced."
Under "AutoArchive," click on "AutoArchive Settings" and review the settings.

**6. Verify Permissions:**

Confirm that the users who have access to the shared mailbox have appropriate permissions to access and view older emails. Ensure that there are no folder-level restrictions in place.

Comment: Hi. 

Thanks for the troubleshooting steps, some of these issues I believe it's because we are using FSLogix profiles hence the catch mode issue.